# Fiddling with lifetimes: sanity check on unsafe reinterpretation of lifetimes

Tags: rust, lifetime, unsafe

Suppose you have two collections (`Vec` for simplicity here) of instances of `T`, and a function to compute whether the elements in those collections appear in either or both of them:

```
// With lifetimes not yet annotated
fn comm(left: &Vec<T>, right: &Vec<T>) -> Vec<(Tag, &T)> {}

enum Tag {
    Left,
    Both,
    Right,
}
```

`comm(l,r)` *guarantees* that the references returned point to elements of the `left` collection in both the case that `T` was present in `left` only, *and* `T` was present in both.

However, because some `T` might appear in `right` only, the function's full signature must look like this:

```
fn comm<'a, 'b, 'c>(left: &'a Vec<T>, right: &'b Vec<T>) -> Vec(Tag, &'c T)
where
  'a: 'c,
  'b: 'c,
```

---

The actual question, then: I know that, within one of the `(tag, &T)` tuples returned `comm`, if `tag == Left or tag == Both`, then `&T` will **surely** point to the `left` collection.

Is it sane, safe, and legitimate to use `mem::transmute` or other mechanism to grab one of the references returned by `comm` and cast it to the lifetime matching the `left` collection?

For instance:

```
fn last_common<'a, 'b>(left: &'a Vec<T>, right: &'b Vec<T>) -> &'a T {
  let tagged = comm(left, right);
  let (tag, ref_to_T) = boring code that picks one tuple from tagged...
  assert!(matches!(tag, Tag::Left) || matches!(tag, Tag::Both))
  return std::mem::transmute::<&'_ T, &'a T>(ref_to_T);
}
```

Comment: I would say yes (it's sound), but I'd choose a different design that avoids the shortening of the lifetime in the first place. I'd have `comm()` return `Vec<(Tag, *const T)>` and use `&*ref_to_T` to cast it to the appropriate lifetime. That signature of `comm()` (that returns a raw pointer) makes it can't represent accurate lifetime information, and that the lifetime is reimbued when the results are interpreted. The raw pointer return will also make it a bit more obvious that doing the wrong thing in `comm()` will cause UB later down the line, even if `comm()` itself is not unsafe.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will keep this approach in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is sound. In fact, the official documentation for `transmute()` says it can be used to extend lifetimes:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.transmute.html#examples

> Extending a lifetime, or shortening an invariant lifetime. This is advanced, very unsafe Rust!
>
> ```rust
> struct R<'a>(&'a i32);
> unsafe fn extend_lifetime<'b>(r: R<'b>) -> R<'static> {
>     std::mem::transmute::<R<'b>, R<'static>>(r)
> }
>
> unsafe fn shorten_invariant_lifetime<'b, 'c>(r: &'b mut R<'static>)
>                                              -> &'b mut R<'c> {
>     std::mem::transmute::<&'b mut R<'static>, &'b mut R<'c>>(r)
> }
> ```

But I will not recommend it. Instead, I'll recommend you to use an enum:

```rust
fn comm<'a, 'b, T>(left: &'a Vec<T>, right: &'b Vec<T>) -> Vec<Tag<'a, 'b, T>> {}

enum Tag<'a, 'b, T> {
    Left(&'a T),
    Both(&'a T), // Could be `&'b T`, too.
    Right(&'b T),
}
```

You can also have a method to extract the value with the shorter lifetime, like:

```rust
impl<'a, T> Tag<'a, 'a, T> {
    pub fn value(self) -> &'a T {
        let (Self::Left(v) | Self::Right(v) | Self::Both(v)) = self;
        v
    }
}
```